# Spring Data JPA: related entity value inserted as null

Tags: database, spring, jpa, crud

I'm very new to Spring Data JPA, so any help is appreciated in advance.

I have a class/entity Request, which is related to another entity Analysis (ManyToOne).  I'm currently using CrudRepository to insert records but when i insert a new Request and provide an Analysis ID, the AnalysisID column in database is left null.  Can anyone explain why?  Below is my code:

Request.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Requests")
@SequenceGenerator(name="req_seq",sequenceName="req_seq",allocationSize=1)
public class Request {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="req_seq")
    @Column(name="RequestID")
    public long id;
    public String pharmacometrician;
    public String programmer;
    public String project;
    public String study;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="AnalysisID")
    public Analysis analysisType;

    @Column(name="WORKINGFOLDERPATH")
    public String folder;

    protected Request() {
    }

    public Request(String pharmacometrician,String programmer,String project, String study,String folderpath,Analysis analysis) {
        Request request = new Request();
        request.pharmacometrician = pharmacometrician;
        request.programmer = programmer;
        request.project = project;
        request.study = study;
        request.folder = folderpath;
        request.analysisType = analysis;
    }
```

Analysis.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ANALYSISTYPES")
@SequenceGenerator(name="analysisid_seq",sequenceName="analysisid_seq",allocationSize=1)
public class Analysis {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="analysisid_seq")
    @Column(name="AnalysisID")
    public long id;
    public String label;
    public String description;

    protected Analysis() {
    }


    public Analysis(String label,String description) {
        this.label = label;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

RequestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("request")
public class RequestController {
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    RequestRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    AnalysisRepository analysisrepo;

    @RequestMapping("newrequest")
    //@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void newRequest(@RequestParam(value="analysis",required=false) long analysisid,
            @RequestParam(value="pm",required=false) String pharmacometrician,
            @RequestParam(value="programer",required=false) String programmer,
            @RequestParam(value="ta",required=false) long taid,
            @RequestParam(value="purpose",required=false) long purposeid,
            @RequestParam(value="project",required=false) String project,
            @RequestParam(value="study",required=false) String study,
            @RequestParam(value="folder",required=false) String folderpath) {
        log.info("New request");
        repository.save(new Request(pharmacometrician,programmer,project,study,folderpath,analysisrepo.findOne(analysisid)));
        return;
        //return repository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

I pass in the analysis id and then get an Analysis object using AnalysisRepository, which then I use to create new Request and save to DB using RequestRepository (extends CrudRepository).  However, when I look in the database, all the fields are populated but the analysisid column is null.

Are these entities not mapping correctly?  Any ideas what could be wrong?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Is analysisrepo.findOne actually returning an instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seemed like analysisrepo.findOne was not returning an instance - thanks Chris.

So, this worked:

```
Analysis a = analysisrepo.findOne(analysisid);
repository.save(new Request(pharmacometrician,programmer,project,study,folderpath,a));
```

Don't know why that was necessary, but at least it's working now.

Thanks!

Comment: You can accept your own answer to record that  the issue is solved.